Pip fails behind proxy using CNTLM
I'm trying to use pip behind corporate proxy on my XFCE 22.04 distro.
First I'd like to point out that I've already read a similar question:  Using pip behind a proxy with CNTLM, but I had no luck with the solution provided there.
I've installed and configured CNTLM which works for other software (eg. APT). Also I've added http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128 and https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:3128 to my environment variables.
Whenever I try to install any package using pip i get: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
I've tried normal python -m pip install and with sudo -E pip install. Then I've tried with --proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128, as well as https and also having the address written with / at the end (as in http://127.0.0.1:3128/)
I've also tried with pip.conf setting CNTLM as proxy there:
[global]
proxy = https://127.0.0.1:3128

Same thing here, all the combination with https and with / at the end.
Any help is really appreciated since I've ran out of ideas
